# publish_post, save_post and wp_after_insert_post triggers are

Tags: php, wordpress, email

For our animalshelter we promote our cats and dogs on our website, facebook and a thirdparty website. There are two ways the stories of the animals appear on our website: directly published and on draft first. This has to do with employees directly publishing their stories, but volunteers also write stories which our employees check before publishing them.

We want to send an email with (1) the content of the (custom) post, (2) with some custom field values of the animals and (3) the pictures of said post after we've published the post for the first time only. So that the stories of the animals can be put online on facebook and the thirdparty website.

However I either get way to many e-mails (on every (auto-)save while creating the post) or my e-mail comes back empty because the custom field values are not loaded (i think...).

I've started with using MailPoet, but I was unable to get the custom fields in the e-mail. So I thought, I'll use php.

This is my current code:

```
add_action( 'publish_kat', 'send_mail_to_user', 100, 2 );
function send_mail_to_user( $post_id ) {
      $post     = get_post($post_id);
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id ); 
      $colour   = get_field('dier_kleur', $post_id);
      $breed    = get_field('dier_ras', $post_id);
      $cast = (get_field("dier_geneutraliseerd") == "1" ? "Ja" : "Nee" );
      $found= (get_field("dier_gevonden") == "1" ? "Ja" : "Nee" );
      $cats = get_field('dier_bij_katten', $post_id);
      $dogs = get_field('dier_bij_honden', $post_id);
      $kkind    = get_field('dier_kleine_kinderen', $post_id);
      $gkind    = get_field('dier_grote_kinderen', $post_id);
      $flat = get_field('dier_flat', $post_id);
      $garden   = get_field('dier_tuin', $post_id);
        $subject  = "Story and pictures from ". "$post_title" ;
        $message  = "Hi , \r\n \r\n This is the story of ". "$post_title". "\r\n \r\n";
        $message .= "Name: ". "$post_title". "\r\n". 
"colour: ". "$colour". "\r\n".
"Breed: ". "$breed". "\r\n \r\n".
"Neutered: ". "$cast". "\r\n".
"Found?: ". "$found". "\r\n".
"Likes other cats?: ". "$cats". "\r\n".
"Likes dogs?: ". "$dogs". "\r\n".
"Likes small children?: ". "$kkind". "\r\n".
"Likes big children?: ". "$gkind". "\r\n".
"Likes a flat?: ". "$flat". "\r\n".
"Likes a garden?: ". "$garden". "\r\n \r\n";
        wp_mail( 'hardcoded-emailadres', $subject, $message );  
}
```

I've started with save_post (save_kat in my case, since my custom post-type is kat), this results in an mostly empty email, because the custom field values stay empty. It works fine when I publish the post from a draft status.

I've also tried publish_post (publish-kat), but then also the custom field values come back empty. Also, this e-mails when the post is updated later on, which I do not want. But then it does show all the values.

Because the values will show in later emails I thought I should delay sending the email. So I tried to use sleep(5), but that made the whole website sleep for 5 secondes. Something I do not want of course ;-)

Some more googling showed me wp_after_insert_post, which I used, but then I get emails with every (auto-)save being made, which I also do not want. But it does however come back with the right email eventually.

I tried to look for all the post-status, but that also didn't help me, because the status changes aren't always te same. I think I'm looking for a combination of publish_post and wp_after_insert_post, but it seems I cannot find the right one. Could someone please push me in the right direction?

Comment: Instead of trying to find a hook or combination thereof, that will always give the correct "result" in all possible cases (like, an already published post gets "downgraded" back to draft, and then published again), it might make more sense to store the info that you already sent such a mail, as meta data on the post ...?

Comment: I'm not yet sure how to store meta data on the post and use that but I'm definately going to look into it. Thank you!